# How to remove the whole div based clicked child using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parent-child, parent

I am trying to delete the closest but all divs are being removed.

Example: if I click `fa-close` under Rooms the `incl-ingd` should be removed

```
<div class="btn-group incl-ingd">
    <div type="button" class="btn btn-default">
        Rooms <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="btn-group incl-ingd">
    <div type="button" class="btn btn-default">
        Mansions <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

As of now I've tried this jQuery:

```
$("i.fa-close").on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).closest('div.incl-ingd').remove();
});
```

But all the `incl-ingd` is being removed.

Is this possible?

Comment: I can't replicate that behaviour - your code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/yxjojLhk/. Could you please add an example of the issue to the question, and also check that there's no other click handlers attached to the `i` element, or its parents, which are affecting the DOM.

Comment: add another class name to parent.When you click fa-close check whether it is under given parent name.If true than remove that div

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Check this script

```js
$(function(){
  $("i.fa-close").on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="btn-group incl-ingd">
    <div type="button" class="btn btn-default">
        Rooms <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="btn-group incl-ingd">
    <div type="button" class="btn btn-default">
        Mansions <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's always better to use `closest()` instead of chained `parent()` calls. Also note that the OPs code works as described, so in theory this doesn't solve anything.

Comment: wow this code `.parent().parent()` works for me! :) thanks @AmanKumar

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working fine, please find the below working snippet

```js
$("i.fa-close").on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).closest('div.incl-ingd').remove();
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn-group incl-ingd">
    <div type="button" class="btn btn-default">
        Rooms <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="btn-group incl-ingd">
    <div type="button" class="btn btn-default">
        Mansions <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well your code works for me. If it doesn't work for you, make sure **font-awesome** and **jQuery** library or CDN has been included properly. If still it doesn't work, then try to use:

```
$("i.fa-close").on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('div.incl-ingd').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery("i.fa-close").click(function(){
     jQuery(this).parents('div').remove();
  );
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/15068505)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("i.fa-close").click(function(){
  $(this).parent().parent().remove()
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="btn-group incl-ingd">
    <div type="button" class="btn btn-default">
        Rooms <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="btn-group incl-ingd">
    <div type="button" class="btn btn-default">
        Mansions <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```